# Access Control inside GridView Pager Template - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, findcontrol, custompaging

I am trying to access a LinkButton that is inside a PagerTemplate in a GridView.

However, I am getting a NullReferenceException and I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I have tried the following...

```
((LinkButton)GridView1.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("lnkbtnPrevious"));
((LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("lnkbtnPrevious"));
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
GridViewRow PagerRow = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
LinkButton b = (LinkButton)PagerRow.FindControl("lnkbtnPrevious"));
```

Comment: fyi - you can't access the pager objects until after DataBind()

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have already created the link button in the PagerTemplate with the ID "lnkbtnPrevious" and the PagerSettings Position="Bottom" the following will get you access to the link button.

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)((GridView1.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("lnkbtnPrevious"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a link button in pagertemplate for gird
and give `id= "LB"`

work this in code in databound event of gridview

```
protected void grid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)grid.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("LB");
}
```

this will work